# ajax live search for post title

Tags: functions, jquery, ajax, html

i m creating a AJAX live search to filter posts title in my wordpress theme. 
As i write something in input it show all the post in result, Not filtering it to get custom post..

**How to search live and find a post with AJAX??**

**Function.php**

```
<?php 
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action','data_fetch');

function data_fetch(){
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array('post_per_page'=>5));
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>

        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;
    die();
}?>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
function fetch(){

    $.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',{'action':'my_action'},
    function(response){
        $('#datafetch').append(response);
        console.log(result);
    });
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="fetch()"></input>
    <div id="datafetch">
</div>
```

Comment: So you want the query to search within post titles ( and the post title keyword is passed via the input in your html form ) ?

Comment: @AhmedElmahdy YES

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a working solution (tested as is)

**The HTML (could be part of page content)**

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()"></input>

<div id="datafetch">Search results will appear here</div>
```

**The JavaScript ( goes to your theme's functions.php )**

```
// add the ajax fetch js
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch(){

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });

}
</script>

<?php
}
```

**And finally the AJAX call** goes to your theme's functions.php

```
// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            
            <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>

        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;

    die();
}
```

Addition:
Here's how I made my AJAX function search precisely:

```
// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

    $the_query = new WP_Query( 
      array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 
        'post_type' => 'post' 
      ) 
    );


    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();

$myquery = esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] );
$a = $myquery;
$search = get_the_title();
if( stripos("/{$search}/", $a) !== false) {?>
            <h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4>
        <?php
                                  }
    endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;

    die();
}
```

Comment: Do you know a way to search the keyword only in title or only in description?

Comment: maybe only using the `posts_where` filter instead of `'s'` like  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298888/wp-query-where-title-begins-with-a-specific-letter)

Comment: I need the posts to be present instead of the "search results will appear here" text, then when the search happens, it just filters the results. is this possible with this method, I currently have this implemented and it works, but I have a blank page, before search happens

Comment: Excellent answer. I only replaced the `post_permalink()` (deprecated) to `get_permalink()`

Answer (score 2):

You forget to call it in as searchinput, you can paste below code in *functions.php*

```
// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>

        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    else: 
        echo '<h3>No Results Found</h3>';
    endif;
        die();
    }

    // add the ajax fetch js
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
    function ajax_fetch() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fetchResults(){
        var keyword = jQuery('#searchInput').val();
        if(keyword == ""){
            jQuery('#datafetch').html("");
        } else {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                type: 'post',
                data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: keyword  },
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
                }
            });
        }

    }
    </script>

    <?php
    }
```

Once you have done, find and open *searchform.php*. Now what you have to do, replace id element with above id element(searchInput) and add this code

```
onkeyup=featechResult()"
```

Next to id element, so overall code will look like this

```
    <form method="get" class="td-search-form-widget" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url( '/' )); ?>">
    <div role="search">
        <input class="td-widget-search-input" type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="searchInput" onkeyup="fetchResults()" /><input class="wpb_button wpb_btn-inverse btn" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php _etd('Search', TD_THEME_NAME)?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Make sure you do changes in the child theme.
Now last step: add `<div id="datafeatch"></div>` just above of  and you can see live search in your search form.

You can also do this via [live search plugin](https://www.mediumtalk.net/wordpress-live-search-plugins/), an easiest way to do if don't know how to code. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Filled in admin profile */
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Extra profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="address"><?php _e("Address"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="postSearch" id="postSearch" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'postSearch', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your address."); ?></span>
            <div id="datafetch"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php }


// the jQuery Ajax call here
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function($){
        var searchRequest = null;

        jQuery(function () {
            var minlength = 3;

            jQuery("#postSearch").keyup(function () {
                var that = this,
                value = jQuery(this).val();

                if (value.length >= minlength ) {
                    if (searchRequest != null) 
                        searchRequest.abort();
                    searchRequest = jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                        data: {

                            action: 'data_fetch',
                            search_keyword : value

                        },
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function(data){
                            //we need to check if the value is the same
                            if (value==jQuery(that).val()) {
                                jQuery('#datafetch').html(data);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }(jQuery));
</script>

<?php
}


// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['search_keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;

    die(); 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

i have been using this plugin :

ajax-search-pro-for-wordpress-live-search-plugin

it is the best plugin

and you can do this in 5 seconds using this.

i have used this plugin in my many Projects.

Comment: Sorry to mention *(and do not take this personal)* but please **don't answer with a plugin suggestion!** I know that users here on wpse can not add a comment till they have a certain amount of reputation points. It is also a known fact that wpse is meant for asking help with coding and not for finding a plugin for which the repository on WordPress.org is meant. Even worse, your advice is for a 3rd party commercial plugin. Imho is this not done and I will flag this answer.