# Search user metadata with checkboxes via ajax (almost working)

Tags: functions, ajax, javascript, search, user-meta

I have created an ajax search form following some tutorials online, it is working but not exactly how I need it to. [Here is where I got the search from](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240138/ajax-live-search-for-post-title).

I have US states setup as a user meta field which is what I want to search against, then display the email addresses of the users in that state.

Right now the ajax search works but only if I search against post titles (using WP_Query). I have been unsuccessful in getting the ajax form to return any user meta search results via WP_Query.

> **Update:**
>   I have come to find that WP_Query was wrong and am now using
>   WP_User_Query, thanks Milo.

Another question, how do I go about getting this to search for multiple strings (like Utah and California)?

> **Update:** I figured out how to search for multiple parameters (at least it is
>   working for me), I added 'meta_compare' => 'IN' to the meta query array.

**Once I can search for multiple strings could I just make regular checkboxes instead of an input text box or is it more involved than that?** This is my last issue I need to resolve.

> **Updated checkbox code**: I have tried changing my search like I found in other questions such as changing the name to an array and onkeyup
>   to onclick but it doesn't work. It does something though as the
>   results say nothing found instead of the placeholder. As far asI could tell the function stays the same with just $_POST['keyword'].

```
<input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]" id="keyword" value="utah" onclick="fetch()" />
```

> **Update:** I found a way to get my checkboxes passed via ajax and get used as a keyword using the code below, but I still have not figured
>   out how to get it to search more than one checkbox at a time (like
>   utah AND california).

**My updated JS for searching (only searches one) checkbox:**

```
 function updateTextArea() {         
     var allVals = [];
     $('#myform :checked').each(function() {
       allVals.push($(this).val());
     });
     //$('#datafetch').val(allVals);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: $('#myform :checked').val() },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#datafetch').val($('#datafetch').val(data).replace("placeholder", data));
    }
    });
  }
```

Here is what I have working so far (code I started with):

```
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch', 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch', 'data_fetch');

function data_fetch() {

    $the_query = new WP_User_Query (array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    's' => esc_attr($_POST['keyword']),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'state',
                'value'   => esc_attr($_POST['keyword']),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
    ))
    );

    $str = '';
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            // $str stuff is for adding a comma between results except for last
            $str .= $str?", 
":'';
            $str .= get_the_author_meta('user_email');
        }
        echo $str;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    }
    die();
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch');

function ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
  success: function(data) {
      // replaces text in an input text box
      $('#datafetch').val($('#datafetch').val(data).replace("placeholder", data));
  }
    });
}
</script>
<?php
}
```

> **Progress Update:** I found a solution after doing more digging on WP_User_Query. I was trying to display the results in a loop like you
>   would when using WP_Query. But I found out you cannot use WP_User_Query in a
>   normal loop. This is the code bit I used to get the ajax search to
>   work by searching user meta fields.

```
function data_fetch() {
    //$name_array = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $search_name);
    $args = array(
        //'role' => 'tour_author',
        'meta_key' => 'state',
        'meta_value' => esc_attr($_POST['keyword']),
        'meta_compare' => '='
    );

    $my_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
    $editors = $my_user_query->get_results();
    $str = '';

    if ( ! empty( $editors ) ) {
        foreach ( $editors as $editor ) {
            $str .= $str?", 
":'';
                $str .= $editor->user_email;
        }
        echo $str;
    } else {
        echo 'No editors found!';
    }
}
```

It works, it produces the results I need but with one issue. It produces a "0" at the end of the string. For example if I search for "Utah" it spits out the proper user but with the zero, so "testuser@test.com0". I have not been able to figure out why as of yet.

> **Update:** Thanks to swissspidys comment I was able to get rid of the trailing zero. I needed to add die() to the end of the function

Comment: its not going to be as easy as all that to go from a single input to multiple, you  need to change the code so it processes each input.

Comment: Your query searches the post title and content, how are you enabling the search within user meta fields? What is the connection between users and tour posts?

Comment: You are correct Milo I need to correct that, I wasn't paying close attention. It was returning search results very similar to what the actual results should be.

Comment: I have tried numerous examples on meta data searching and I cannot get any of them to work. They all don't return any results. I suspect this has something to do with the javascript/ajax, which I am no good at.

Comment: User meta is associated with users, not posts. You need [`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) to find users, not `WP_Query`.

Comment: Your ajax callback needs to use `die()` at the end to stop output.

Comment: Thanks swissspidy that did that trick and got rid of the trailing zero.