# How get get list of pages in ajax search

Tags: pages, ajax, search, title

I am trying to follow [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240138/ajax-live-search-for-post-title) solution, it is kind of working but I need a list of pages rather than posts.

This is the code that I am working with using Codex information from wordpress but I am getting no results.

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( 
$_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'page' ) );
if( $the_query->get_pages() ) :
    while( $the_query->get_pages() ): $the_query->get_pages(); ?>

        <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>

    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();  
endif;

die();
}
```

Ajax Call:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() {
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function fetch(){
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
    type: 'page',
    data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
    }
});
}
</script>
```

HTML Form:

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()"></input>
<div id="datafetch">Search results will appear here</div>
```

Could someone please point me towards the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Maybe try removing the die() within the data_fetch() function?

Comment: that didn't worked bro.. is their anything i can do to it to show list of pages rather than posts please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `get_pages()` method in the [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#methods) `class` (for WordPress version 4.9.4).

So in the `data_fetch()` `function`, replace the following:

```
if( $the_query->get_pages() ) :
    while( $the_query->get_pages() ): $the_query->get_pages(); ?>
```

..with this:

```
if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

And in the `fetch()` JS `function`, set the `type` to `POST`, like so:

```
function fetch(){
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
    }
});
}
```

Hint: In the `data_fetch()` `function`, I suggest you to use `wp_die()` instead of `die()`. You should also use `wp_reset_query()` in place of `wp_reset_postdata()` because you're making a custom `WP_Query` call.

[EDIT] In reply to the following comment:

> Can i please ask on how I can show child pages only of a parent page?

In the HTML form, you can add a hidden `input` which stores the parent page's ID. And then add the value to the `data` in the AJAX request. Then in the `WP_Query` call (in the `data_fetch()` `function`), you can use `post_parent` to set the parent page's ID.

See sample code [here](https://pastebin.com/yPaJzSKe).

Comment: Thank you very much Sally for the information and for helping out. That worked perfectly :) Can i please ask on how I can show child pages only of a parent page? Thank you once again.. it got me a step ahead :)

Comment: I've updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Or if you don't need to use a dynamic parent page's ID, then you can set a static one directly in the `data_fetch()` `function`. So you'd add `post_parent => 123` after the `post_type => 'page'` in the `WP_Query` call.

Comment: OMG!!! this is pure gold!!!.. Thank you soo much Sally for your help.. really appreciate it very much. (it won't let me upvote your answer as my rep is below 15 being a newbie.. I will upvote it as soon my rep reaches 15).. Thank you once again Sally and have a brilliant day :)

Comment: regarding the static Id's... thank you for the detailed answer I was going to use static ID's as how the website been developed by a previous developer. Thank you soo much for providing immense amount of quality help and information. Really appreciate it and God Bless :) Have a brilliant day :)

Comment: It's my pleasure helping you, and all the best with the website! =)

Comment: Thank you very much Sally :) .. just one question.. is it possible to show child pages on non parent pages to like Contact us, Index as the search is only working on parent pages. Sorry to be so much trouble and thanks once again :)

Comment: It is possible, if you set the `post_parent` to the right value. E.g. You have a Page named "My Parent Page" with the ID of `456`; so you can set `post_parent` to `456` to search for Pages that are children of the "My Parent Page". But I'm not too sure if you're referring to the PHP `function` (i.e. `data_fetch()`).

Comment: Thank you Sally :) I am trying to show the child pages (which are products) to be able to show in the search results across the whole website. It works on parent pages but not on pages that doesn't have child page i.e. Index, About Us, Contact Us. Thank you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75183/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-pv619).

Comment: thank you for resolving this issue out Sally :) the best Wordpress programmer - God Bless :)